# How to insert a row in Javascript with a loop?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json file and I want to convert the data into a table with Javascript. I found some similar questions [How to convert the following table to JSON with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927126/how-to-convert-the-following-table-to-json-with-javascript) , [loop through a json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48785804/loop-through-a-json-object), but they all use jQuery and show the table on html web. I just need a simple loop to insert row into the table. I tried 'append', 'insert' and 'insertRow', all not work. Could anyone give me a hint?

Json file:

```
{
"name": "lily",
"country": "china",
"age": 23
},
{
"name": "mike",
"country": "japan",
"age": 22
},
{
"name": "lucy",
"country": "korea",
"age": 25
 }
```

My code:

```
    var jdata = {};
    jdata.cols = [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "label": "name",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "label": "country",
            "type":"string"
        }
    ];

    for(var i = 1; i < 3; i++){
        row = [
            {
                "c": [
                    {
                      "v": json["hits"]["hits"][i]["_source"]["name"]         
                    },
                    {
                       "v": json["hits"]["hits"][i]["_source"]["country"]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];
        jdata.rows.insertRow(row);
    }
```

Edit: Add expected output: change the json file to the following structure.

```
[
    ['lily', 'china'],
    ['mike', 'japan'],
    ['lucy', 'korea'], 
  ]
```

Comment: you could always convert the json to a normal array then append the dat you want and then convert it back to json

Comment: Please explain what this part is supposed to be and how it pertains to the rest of the code? `"v": json["hits"]["hits"][i]["_source"]...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/push) (Or [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) / push(...elements) if you want to add array of rows)

```
    jdata.rows = [];
    for(var i = 1; i < 3; i++){
        row = [
            {
                "c": [
                    {
                      "v": json["hits"]["hits"][i]["_source"]["name"]         
                    },
                    {
                       "v": json["hits"]["hits"][i]["_source"]["country"]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];
        jdata.rows.push(row);
        // for elements from row
        // jdata.rows.push(...row)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. 'push' is a nice way. but I get error 'Cannot read property '0' of undefined' back. Did I misunderstand array and json data?

Comment: Which line is that? In this code only thing I can see with numeric index is `json["hits"]["hits"][i]`. Try to `console.log(json["hits"])` and check values in element's inspector console (proly `ctrl+shift+i`)

Comment: I tried 'console.log(json["hits"]["hits"])' and the result is the correct json that I want.

Comment: I find the problem of 'Cannot read property '0' of undefined'. remove one bracket in the code: row = [ { "c":...} ] => row = {"c"...}. It works nice now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few errors in your code

1. The JSON needs to be an array so you can loop through each object to display.
2. `insertRow()` is a method from the Table object, `jdata.rows` is not a Table object but an array.

Since, you have used `insertRow()`, I have rewritten your code to display the table data using the Table Object methods. Here is a code snippet

**Edit:** You can use the `push()` method to create your required JSON structure. I have edited the code snippet to create your required JSON.

```js
var jdata = {
  cols: [{
      "id": "1",
      "label": "name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "label": "country",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ],
  rows: []
};

var persons = [{
    "name": "lily",
    "country": "china",
    "age": 23
  },
  {
    "name": "mike",
    "country": "japan",
    "age": 22
  }, {
    "name": "lucy",
    "country": "korea",
    "age": 25
  }
];

var table = document.getElementById("table");
var header = table.createTHead();
var footer = table.createTFoot();
var rowHeader = header.insertRow(0);

jdata.cols.forEach((col, index) => {
  var cell = rowHeader.insertCell(index);
  cell.innerHTML = col.label;
});

persons.forEach((person, index) => {
  var rowFooter = footer.insertRow(index);
  rowFooter.insertCell(0).innerHTML = person.name;
  rowFooter.insertCell(1).innerHTML = person.country;
  
  jdata.rows.push([person.name, person.country]);
});

console.log(jdata.rows);
```

```html
<table id="table">

</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear comment! but I don't want the table showed on the web. I want to transfer the json file to the new structure(edited).

Comment: @landy I have edited my answer to include your new JSON structure.